# PHP phpredis error when trying to pass config options while instantiating Redis class

Tags: php, redis, instantiation, phpredis

I have next setup:

- PHP 8.1
- Redis 7.0.11 - latest version
- phpredis 5.3.7 - latest version

When I try to instantiate Redis class like this:

```
$redis = new Redis([
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => 6379,
    'connectTimeout' => 2.5,
    'auth' => 'password',
    'ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false],
    'backoff' => [
        'algorithm' => Redis::BACKOFF_ALGORITHM_DECORRELATED_JITTER,
        'base' => 500,
        'cap' => 750
    ]
]);
```

I get the next error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Redis::__construct() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given...**

Looks like constructor does not accept any arguments, but according to documentation it [should](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#usage).

When I try to instantiate class without config options passed, everything works as expected.

I've googled but could not find any mentioning of this error on the web, please help!

Comment: From that page you linked: "_Starting from version 6.0.0 it's possible to specify configuration options._"

Comment: @brombeer I thought it refers to Redis version, 5.3.7 is the latest and in a 2 week old issues thread they state that "Documentation describes current development version" - https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/2341#issuecomment-1501049379 .

Comment: `5.3.7.` is the latest _stable_ version/release. `develop` should be ahead of `stable` with features not yet released

Comment: @brombeer got it, still learning this github stuff. I was looking for a v 6.0.0. branch and didn't find one so assumed the 6.0.0. was referring to Redis.